# Is there a performance penalty associated with methods created in the constructor versus methods created on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, performance, idioms

I can declare methods of an object in two ways:

The first way uses the `self=this` idiom.

```
function SelfIdiomExample(name){
    var self = this;

    self.sayHello = function (name){
         alert("Hello, "+name);
    }
}
```

Which is useful when you need a reference to the object in a method (for example if the method will be passed as a callback). The other way is to do it by modifying the prototype:

```
function PrototypeModExample(){
   //pass
}

PrototypeModExample.prototype.sayHello = function(name){
   alert("Hello, "+name);
}
```

Both have the same result:

```
var sieg = new SelfIdiomExample();
var pmeg = new PrototypeModExample();

sieg.sayHello("Barnaby");
pmeg.sayHello("Josephine");
```

While I understand the use case for the `self=this` idiom, I am wondering:

**Is there a performance penalty to using the methods created in the constructor versus methods created on the prototype?**

Comment: It is just an assigning reference to a variable. http://jsperf.com/ - use it to measure the "difference" PS: in first case you actually don't need `self` at all

Comment: http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-self

Comment: You can always get a reference to the object in prototype methods using `this`. Also you are missing `var` in the first snippet.

Comment: **Please don't forget to declare your local variables with `var` !!!**

Comment: @zerkms That's a really useful tool. Thanks! It answers my question. I'd like to know more about what exactly is going on underneath though.

Comment: For most practical purposes (unless you are, for some reason, writing code that passes around direct references to `sayHello`) the `self = this;` in the first example is unnecessary.  You could just omit it and avoid the question of performance entirely.

Comment: @brice: underneath of what? Of `var self = this;` assignment? You just assign a reference to `this` to `self` variable. So it's really cheap operation.

Comment: @aroth, yes, I know. This is just a minimal example. The _actual_ code **has** to use `self=this` since some of the methods are used in callbacks.

Comment: @zerkms I don't call 34% slower than prototype methods cheap when the objects in question number in the 100000s and are part of a webgl scene.

Comment: @brice: uhm, that 34% difference is using prototype vs using `this.function`. Not `self = this` difference. I was answering your **initial** question about how fast `self = this` is. The answer is it's terribly fast. Your latest question revision is about prototyping vs `this.func = ...`. The answer is: prototyping is much faster

Comment: Apologies, @zerkms. I didn't word my question properly in the first place. You're right, of course, I never expected the difference to be in the var assignment, but in how the methods are declared, and was just wondering how bad it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this here:

```
var self = this;
```

Is not something has performance implications at all.  It's wicked fast as it's simply accessing a local variable.  Even from nested funcitons, this is a very fast operation in JavaScript.

However, methods created in the constructor versus methods created on the prototype has a huge performance difference.

In this example:

```
var PrototypeModExample = function(){
  this.name = "Joe";
};

PrototypeModExample.prototype.sayHello = function(){
   alert("Hello, " + this.name);
};

var a = new PrototypeModExample();
var b = new PrototypeModExample();
console.log(a.sayHello === b.sayHello); // true
```

Every instance of the constructor gets access to the same *function objects*. Which can be proved by using the `===` operator to compare the function objects on two instances.  It will only return `true` when they are the *same object*.  So globally we now have 2 instances, but they share one function object for the implementation of the `sayHello` method.  This means that function is already setup and created when you want to make a new instance.

In other words, for all instance `obj.sayHello` points to the same function object, which was created before any instances existed at all.

---

But this on the the other hand:

```
function SelfIdiomExample(name){
    var self = this;
    this.name = "Joe";

    this.sayHello = function(){
         alert("Hello, " + self.name);
    }
}

var a = new SelfIdiomExample();
var b = new SelfIdiomExample();
console.log(a.sayHello === b.sayHello); // false
```

Works differently.  Now we see that the `===` comparison is false.  That's because a *new function object* was created for each instance.  Creating this function takes time (it needs to be parsed) and memory (this unique version of that function needs to be stored).  So when creating lots of these instances, this method will be both slower and consume more memory.

In other words, for all instance `obj.sayHello` points to a unique function object which was created when the instance itself was created.

---

So usually, the prototype method is preferred.  Especially in cases where a large number of instance might exist, since each instance can share function objects for it's methods.

Comment: Thanks Alex, In retrospect, I should have tested that before asking the question! It's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As always, you have to test in order to answer questions like this: http://jsperf.com/this-vs-self/2.

When you test, there appears to be not much difference (less than few percent with a slight advantage to `self` in some cases).  One advantage to `self` is that it can be minimized better by changing it to a one character variable name and that is apparently why some frameworks use it.

In your example, I would say that the use of `self` is extranous and not neccessary.  Normally folks only use `self` when a closure is used and the value of `this` in some callback is no longer what you want it to be like this:

```
counter.prototype.incrementWithDelay(delay) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.counter++;
    }, delay);
}
```

But, if you just have a normal method, there is little reason to use `self`.

```
counter.prototype.set(val) {
    this.counter = val;
}
```